# Lookup field not finding records

Tags: lookup

I have a lookup field in the Opportunity Page, which allows me to look for a record from a custom object. This shouldn't matter, but I'm not able to find in the lookup field unless I search by the first word of the record in the custom object. For example:

**Search in lookup field:**  Truck
**Results:** Truck GM

**Search in look field:** GM
**Results:** no results...

How can I solve this issue? Or is it just a limitation in Salesforce?

Comment: Have you tried using wildcard (`*`) characters? Searching `* GM` should work...

Comment: Does the opportunity have a related `Account` record? I worked in an org where we had this issue and our SF support rep told us something to the effect of "Yeah it's weird... just put an account on it".

Comment: Ah. I was adding the (*) after. Makes sense. Thank you Adrian!